# Tensorflow allocating all memory for any program

Tags: tensorflow

- **OS Platform and Distribution (e.g., Linux Ubuntu 16.04)**: linux Ubuntu 16.04
- **TensorFlow installed from (source or binary)**: binary
- **TensorFlow version (use command below)**: v1.4.0-rc1
- **Python version**: 3.5.5
- **CUDA/cuDNN version**: CUDA 8.0 / cuDNN 6
- **GPU model and memory**: nvidia gtx 1080

I am new to Tensorflow. So this could easily be some silly installation error that I don't see.

I open python to test TF installation:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
print(device_lib.list_local_devices())
```

Resulting in:

```
 I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:137] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX
2018-04-11 21:39:44.830140: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1030] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX 1080 major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.8475
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0
totalMemory: 7.92GiB freeMemory: 78.94MiB
2018-04-11 21:39:44.830178: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1120] Creating TensorFlow device (/device:GPU:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1080, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
2018-04-11 21:39:44.832231: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:936] failed to allocate 78.94M (82771968 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
2018-04-11 21:39:44.834394: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:936] failed to allocate 71.04M (74494976 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
2018-04-11 21:39:44.835825: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:936] failed to allocate 63.94M (67045632 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
2018-04-11 21:39:44.837560: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:936] failed to allocate 57.55M (60341248 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
2018-04-11 21:39:44.839233: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:936] failed to allocate 51.79M (54307328 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
2018-04-11 21:39:44.841757: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:936] failed to allocate 46.61M (48876800 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
2018-04-11 21:39:44.843632: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:936] failed to allocate 41.95M (43989248 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
2018-04-11 21:39:44.845588: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:936] failed to allocate 37.76M (39590400 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
2018-04-11 21:39:44.847229: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:936] failed to allocate 33.98M (35631360 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
2018-04-11 21:39:44.849278: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:936] failed to allocate 30.58M (32068352 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
2018-04-11 21:39:44.850967: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:936] failed to allocate 27.52M (28861696 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
[name: "/device:CPU:0"
device_type: "CPU"
memory_limit: 268435456
locality {
}
incarnation: 6037705122138393497
, name: "/device:GPU:0"
device_type: "GPU"
memory_limit: 82771968
locality {
  bus_id: 1
}
incarnation: 11403601020071115295
physical_device_desc: "device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1080, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 6.1"
]
```

Comment: What is your real question? Do you want to allocate memory or not? Or you want to restrict based no priority?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing your question is *"Why does Tensorflow allocate all available GPU memory even though much less memory would be enough for my program?"*, then the answer is that they do this to reduce GPU memory fragmentation. You can change this default behavior with some settings like `config.gpu_options.allow_growth` and `config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction` to make Tensorflow less memory hungry at the expense of allowing some potential memory fragmentation to occur. Detailed explanation in the [Tensorflow Programmer's Guide *Using GPU* chapter](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/using_gpu#allowing_gpu_memory_growth).